# Django CreateView: automatically set two foreign key fields in a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called "Booking" where events are booked between a user and an expert. I'm trying to set the booking CreateView to automatically know the current user and the expert who's profile the user was visiting so that these two users do not need to be selected from dropdown menus in the booking form. I am able to do this successfully for the current user by overriding the form_valid method, but not sure how to do this for the expert.

models.py:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expert = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bookings')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Video call with ..', null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField('Start time', null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField('End time', null=True)
    notes = models.TextField('Notes', help_text='Please provide some detail on what you would like to learn or discuss', blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class BookingView(CreateView):
    model = Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', include('booking.urls')),
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), {'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
    path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.view_profile, name='profile_with_pk'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/booking/', BookingView.as_view(), name='user_booking_new'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.EditProfileView, name='edit_profile'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've tried setting "form.instance.expert" to the form_valid method, but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* did you set it to, and exactly what happened? Where is the value supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I tried to add the line:  form.instance.expert = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk) and also tried form.instance.expert = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')) but neither worked. The value of the pk is the user pk (in this case the expert, as you can see in the url for view_profile). When a user visits a profile and wants to book that expert, I want the pk for that user profile to be automatically passed into the form somehow so the booking form knows who the expert is already if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, the second of those should have worked. What happened when you tried it? What error did you get?

Comment: You're right, the second option is actually working! I was getting confused because the dropdown menu was still appearing on the form. I think I simply need to exclude it from the form. The booking is working as specified. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Answered my question with the help of the comment above. Answer is in views.py:

```
class BookingView(CreateView):
    model = Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.expert = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
```